# Apply css stylesheet to Firefox extension

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm having a problem applying css styles to my Firefox extension elements.

```
chrome  
  -content ->attach.xul,cap.js  
  -skin->overlay.css
```

In cap.js I'm creating a table and appending it to the body of the page. I tried to style this table. However, when I tested this extension, I found that the table and button elements in the extension are changing according to the site I'm visiting. I've applied this as inline style; yet the design is still changing.

I tried to register a skin for this extension, but the styles were not applied.

In attach.xul I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://capture/skin/overlay.css" type="text/css"?>
```

In manifest file I have this:

```
content     capture    chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://capture/content/attach.xul
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly? You apply `overlay.css` to the browser XUL (indirectly, via `attach.xul`) but expect it to apply to content pages?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is styling content pages rather than adding styles to the user interface of your extension, [nsIStyleSheetService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIStyleSheetService) is your friend. Something like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var styleSheetService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
var uri = Services.io.newURI("chrome://capture/skin/overlay.css", null, null);
styleSheetService.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, styleSheetService.USER_SHEET);
```

Make sure to use [@-moz-document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@document) in `overlay.css` so that your styles are applied only to the pages that they belong to - these rules will be applied to all web pages (and even browser's XUL) otherwise.

Comment: Thanks wladimir, but i'm trying to apply styles for my extension elements. this extension contains table,input and buttons. so i have styles for elements in the style sheet[overlay.css] and i want to use it, for that i tried above method and it didn't worked.

Comment: @Sekar: From your description it sounds like you are injecting that table into a web page - then it is no longer "my extension elements".

Comment: I'm new to this category [ developing extensions ]. so i chosen this method. but by doing this designs of external websites affecting my table design even if i give inline styles.  Is there any methods available to create tables..